# Check if a key is present in any of the dictionaries in a tuple containing multiple dictionaries returned by a function

Tags: python, dictionary

Is it possible to have a function return two dictionaries in a tuple and check to see if a value in a dictionary is inside the function returning two dictionaries? Ex-

```
def fooBar():
    a = {"foo": "bar"}
    b = {"bar": "foo"}
    return (a,b)


c = {"foo":"bar"}
for key, value in c.items():
    print(key in fooBar())
```

I want to check if `key` in `c` is found somewhere in my function `fooBar()`.. Which should, as the `key` in `c`  is `"foo"`, and one of the keys in `fooBar()` is `"foo"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check if they keys in one dictionary are in the values of the dictionaries returned by the function you could do something like this:

```
for key in c.keys():
    for dictionary in foobar():
        if key in dictionary.values():
            print("Found: ", key)
```

Comment: you might need to change `c.items()` to `c.keys()` so that it actually works.